# Creating a makefile and compiling in subdirectories too

Tags: c++

There is this nice makefile (from this tutorial: https://sites.google.com/site/michaelsafyan/software-engineering/how-to-write-a-makefile). However, also as mentioned on the web site, this makefile compiles all the .c and .cpp files from **single directory** to an executable.

```
program_NAME := myprogram
program_C_SRCS := $(wildcard *.c)
program_CXX_SRCS := $(wildcard *.cpp)
program_C_OBJS := ${program_C_SRCS:.c=.o}
program_CXX_OBJS := ${program_CXX_SRCS:.cpp=.o}
program_OBJS := $(program_C_OBJS) $(program_CXX_OBJS)
program_INCLUDE_DIRS :=
program_LIBRARY_DIRS :=
program_LIBRARIES :=

CPPFLAGS += $(foreach includedir,$(program_INCLUDE_DIRS),-I$(includedir))
LDFLAGS += $(foreach librarydir,$(program_LIBRARY_DIRS),-L$(librarydir))
LDFLAGS += $(foreach library,$(program_LIBRARIES),-l$(library))

.PHONY: all clean distclean

all: $(program_NAME)

$(program_NAME): $(program_OBJS)
    $(LINK.cc) $(program_OBJS) -o $(program_NAME)

clean:
    @- $(RM) $(program_NAME)
    @- $(RM) $(program_OBJS)

distclean: clean
```

How is it possible to modify this makefile such that it compiles following program? e.g., if my directories have following structure:

```
/project
    Makefile
    main.cpp
    /src
        Class1.cpp
        Class2.cpp
    /obj
        Class1.obj
        Class2.obj
    /bin
        myProgram
    /inc
        Class1.h
        Class2.h
    /lib
        libX.a
```

Comment: Please try to change it first. Look carefully at the makefile and see what is defined where that you can modify...

Comment: In your place I would investigate build system generators like cmake, autotools and the like. Hand-crafting Makefiles is error-prone and also hard to extend.

Comment: @arne: well.. maybe just I have invested already some time in learning makefiles, so would like to bring it to the end

Comment: @pseudonym_127 Then congratulations on some wasted time. Now it's up to you to decide if you want to waste more time, or simply use something like Waf, CMake or SCons (Autotools actually aren't that good either, at least in my opinion).

Comment: @Bartek Banachewicz: And how long does it take to learn using CMake? Just in my company make was used, so I decided to stick to it.

Comment: @pseudonym_127 It took me about 3 hours to learn SCons enough to use it in my projects.

Comment: @ Bartek Banachewicz: Scons, now Cmake, it's getting to much :) I was recommended CMake, you think CScons is worthy alternative to Cmake?

Comment: Learning Makefile is actually a good idea because it is the most widely used build system. I agree that it is error prone to use but if you are in a company/team that uses Makefile they you dont really have a choice. Scons is good but it is really slow. For small projects it wouldn't matter though. For my personal projects I use CMake, it is easy to learn and use.

Comment: @Aditya Kumar: Yes and the a bit "sad" thing is I already invested some time in learning makefiles... For Scons and CMake, which is easier to learn/use? (the fact that it's slow, I don't think it is a big problem for me).

Comment: `CMake` is easier to learn in my opinion. If you know python then `Scons` would be easy to learn, it is just python code that you have to write/modify. But if you like 'Makefile' go ahead and learn it because that is most rewarding (in profession) and once you know Makefile learning other build systems becomes easier.

Answer (score 0):

Dan. As others have mentioned in the comments, you really ought to use CMake or some other build system that generates makefiles (and other projects) rather than creating a makefile by hand.

With the makefile that I provided in the tutorial, it's important to understand what each of the various variables represent. The `program_C_SRCS` and `program_CXX_SRCS` represent the C and C++ source files that are to be built. You can modify the wildcard such that they are picked up from the "src" directory rather than from the current directory. Likewise, the `OBJS` variables define the list of object files that are produced as output. You can similarly modify the way that this is constructed so that they get emitted in the "obj" subdirectory (though without further testing, I'm unsure whether the normal inference that x.o is generated from x.cpp will survive if they span different directories... you'll have to see for yourself).

As for including the headers from a different directory, the `program_INCLUDE_DIRS` is defined for this very purpose. Just use `program_INCLUDE_DIRS := inc`, and the "inc" folder should be added to the list of directory for which to search for includes. Likewise, you can link against the library libX.a library by adding the "lib" directory to `program_LIBRARY_DIRS` and adding "X" to `program_LIBRARIES`.

In any event, knowing how makefiles work is useful both for historical purposes and for debugging / understanding how the tools that generate makefiles work. However, it is really inadvisable in this day and age to write your own makefiles. Please, please, please invest some time into learning [CMake](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/documentation.html). While there is some upfront time investment in learning a new tool such as CMake, it will save you a lot of time in the long run over writing extremely contorted Makefiles that are fragile and slow to build.

Comment: Michael thanks I will considering learning CMake. But for the moment - since I've already spent some time with makefiles - can you please look at this makefile I created: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17442609/what-else-should-i-learn-about-makefiles ?? I think it is an OK makefile, in the sense that I will be able to use it for projects with "average" complexity right? (given I also understand that makefile more or less).