# how to create a makefile with system header files

Tags: c++, ssl, makefile, openssl

I am trying to create a makefile using the help of [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17361113/creating-a-makefile-and-compiling-in-subdirectories-too), I changed the code provided a little bit since I have many `*.c` files that need to be compiled.
this the project hierarchy:

```
/coap
    Makefile
    /src
        /src
            /coap
                /imc
                    *.h files
                /src
                    *.c files
            /system
                /imc
                    client.h
                /src
                    client.c
            **makefile**
    /files
        sdk.sh
```

I  made the first makefile and it seems to work fine, but my problem is with the second one written in bold.

Here, I provide the changes that I made:

```
program_NAME := coap
program_C_SRCS += \
/home/iat2/Projects/XXXX/package/coap/src/src/coap/src/address.c \
/home/iat2/Projects/XXXX/package/coap/src/src/coap/src/async.c \
/home/iat2/Projects/XXXX/package/coap/src/src/coap/src/block.c \
/home/iat2/Projects/XXXX/package/coap/src/src/coap/src/coap_asn1.c \
/home/iat2/Projects/XXXX/package/coap/src/src/coap/src/coap_cache.c \
/home/iat2/Projects/XXXX/package/coap/src/src/coap/src/coap_debug.c \
/home/iat2/Projects/XXXX/package/coap/src/src/coap/src/coap_event.c \
/home/iat2/Projects/XXXX/package/coap/src/src/coap/src/coap_gnutls.c \
/home/iat2/Projects/XXXX/package/coap/src/src/coap/src/coap_hashkey.c \
/home/iat2/Projects/XXXX/package/coap/src/src/coap/src/coap_io.c \
/home/iat2/Projects/XXXX/package/coap/src/src/coap/src/coap_mbedtls.c \
/home/iat2/Projects/XXXX/package/coap/src/src/coap/src/coap_notls.c \
/home/iat2/Projects/XXXX/package/coap/src/src/coap/src/coap_openssl.c \
/home/iat2/Projects/XXXX/package/coap/src/src/coap/src/coap_prng.c \
/home/iat2/Projects/XXXX/package/coap/src/src/coap/src/coap_session.c \
/home/iat2/Projects/XXXX/package/coap/src/src/coap/src/coap_tcp.c \
/home/iat2/Projects/XXXX/package/coap/src/src/coap/src/coap_time.c \
/home/iat2/Projects/XXXX/package/coap/src/src/coap/src/coap_tinydtls.c \
/home/iat2/Projects/XXXX/package/coap/src/src/coap/src/encode.c \
/home/iat2/Projects/XXXX/package/coap/src/src/coap/src/mem.c \
/home/iat2/Projects/XXXX/package/coap/src/src/coap/src/net.c \
/home/iat2/Projects/XXXX/package/coap/src/src/coap/src/option.c \
/home/iat2/Projects/XXXX/package/coap/src/src/coap/src/pdu.c \
/home/iat2/Projects/XXXX/package/coap/src/src/coap/src/resource.c \
/home/iat2/Projects/XXXX/package/coap/src/src/coap/src/str.c \
/home/iat2/Projects/XXXX/package/coap/src/src/coap/src/subscribe.c \
/home/iat2/Projects/XXXX/package/coap/src/src/coap/src/uri.c 

program_C_OBJS := ${program_C_SRCS:.c=.o}

program_OBJS := $(program_C_OBJS) 
program_INCLUDE_DIRS :=/home/iat2/Projects/XXXX/package/coap/src/src/coap/imc
program_LIBRARY_DIRS :=
program_LIBRARIES := router

CFLAGS += $(foreach includedir,$(program_INCLUDE_DIRS),-I$(includedir))
LDFLAGS += $(foreach librarydir,$(program_LIBRARY_DIRS),-L$(librarydir))
LDFLAGS += $(foreach library,$(program_LIBRARIES),-l$(library))

.PHONY: all clean distclean

all: $(program_NAME)

$(program_NAME): $(program_OBJS)
    $(LINK.cc) $(program_OBJS) -o $(program_NAME)
clean:
    @- $(RM) $(program_NAME)
    @- $(RM) $(program_OBJS)

distclean: clean
```

When I try to compile, the log file output is:

```sh
fatal error: sys/random.h: No such file or directory
 #include <sys/random.h>
```

and it can't recognize some of the openssl functions written in the `coap_openssl.c` file.

Comment: Is `random.h` on your system?  Is `sys` included in the _path_ variable?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "the _path_ variable".  Anyway, to the OP: we cannot help because you didn't provide the most important information: you didn't show us the compile line that was invoked when you got this error, and you didn't tell use where the `sys/random.h` header file can be found.  If we don't know where it is, we certainly can't figure out how to tell make where it is.

Comment: actually, i don't know where `random.h` is located. i figured its a file belongs to the system, and this project was created using eclipse IDE for C/C++ and it works fine, right now, am doing a cross compilation. maybe, that's why it cant find the `random.h` file ?

Comment: you asked for the compile line i just enter `make install` in terminal  that's all.

Comment: That does not [appear to be](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/header) a standard header.  You need to understand where the headers are for the cross compilation environment and look to see what is present.  The problem doesn't seem to have anything to do with your makefile or project layout, but is just what the error states: you don't have that file available.

Comment: (A) What is the name of your library ? (If it's `librouter.a`: The setting for `program_LIBRARIES` seems right. But probably you need to add its directory to `program_LIBRARY_DIRS`) Do this for your libraries. (B) The thread you mention in the 1st line of your question doesn't define `$(LINK.cc)`, I suppose it includes `$(CC)`, `$(CFLAGS)`, `$(LDFLAGS)` etc. (C) I don't see an `install:` target in the makefile you've posted. Maybe typing `make` in the command line is enough. (D) If you can't create a correct makefile, maybe it's best to check CMake (as advised by Michael Safyan). Good luck !

Comment: @JDługosz the problem was with my sdk `random.h` file, i tested the`sys/time.h` and it worked fine, after trying to launch without defining the `random.h` file the compilation worked too.
@SiddharthaShivshankar, actually my project  is the source code of the coap library ( after minor changes ofc), and the `install:` target is written in the first makefile located at the main folder.